# constructor called in main, but object not created properly

Tags: c++, constructor, output

I am trying to call the constructor H, but for some reason its not being called.
I get no error when I compile my code, and I get the output:

> A object initialized.
>
> H object initialized.

If H was initialized properly, the cout from the constructor should also be shown.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

I also have another question. How can I change the value of hVec[i].a and have the value of
aArray[i].a take upon this value as well? I know I am suppose to use pointers, but an very confused. Sorry for all the questions; I'm reltaively new to programming in C++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A(int av):a(av){}
     
    int a;
};

struct Heap
{
  
  Heap(std::vector<A> hVal)
  {
      std::cout << "Constructor for H object. \n";
      for (int i=0; i<hVal.size(); ++i) 
      {
          hVec.push_back(hVal[i]);
          std::cout << "hVec[i].a = " << hVec[i].a << "   ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  
  std::vector<A> hVec;
};


int main()
{
  A a0(2), a1(4), a2(8);  
  std::vector<A> aArray;  
  aArray.push_back(a0);
  aArray.push_back(a1);
  aArray.push_back(a2);         
  std::cout << "A object initialized. \n";

  Heap h(A);

  std::cout << "H object initialized. \n";
  
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `struct Heap` does not have a constructor which takes `A` as argument.

However, you can initialize h with aArray which is `std::vector<A>` type

```
Heap h(aArray);
```

In C++, unless you are trying to be compatible with C, otherwise just use `class` instead of `struct`

Comment: There no warning, as he Heap h(A) is treated as a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
Heap h(A);
```

This declares a function of type `Heap(A)` named `h`.  Perhaps you meant:

```
Heap h(aArray);
```

This declares a local variable of type `Heap` named `h`.

Answer (score 0):

use `Heap h(aArray);` instead of `Heap h(A);`

The line `Heap h(A);` declares a function `h` taking an object of type `A` as parameter, and returns an object `Heap`.